AAD B2C Cutom policy customize errors in http response
When a user does not authenticate successfully with the service this message is returned in the response body:
{
    "status": "400",
    "errorCode": "AADB2C90053",
    "message": "Invalid username or password."
}

Is there any way to change the default errorCode and/or message? I´m using custom policies.
Tried to search MS online documentation.

What you are trying to achieve after changing the default message could help assist your question.
If it is just to show a different message instead of "Invalid username or password.", you could do something like this.
Identify which technical profile is used for login. It is generally named as 'SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin' and it is likely the first technical profile referenced in your first orchestration step.
Add a Item Key as follows to that technical profile:
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="DefaultMessage">Here goes your custom text</Item>
        {other Item Key}
      </Metadata>

If you have any other specific custom user flow if the credential is invalid, you would need more tweaking to your custom policies.
